# Multithread without tightly coupled objects

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm trying to build a simple game in Java. Ran into the problem of the JTextPanel not updating until after the game loop terminates, which of course, isn't a good experience for the player.

I'm unfamiliar with multithreading but trying to figure it out. I can run separate code now in multiple threads, but I can't get my head around how to have the Threads interact. It's highly likely I'm missing something simple, but I can't find it by searching, so I throw myself at your mercy. I'm hanging by a thread...

Controller class and main thread. I need the gamePanel and the game to run separately. I've tried to run the Game class in a separate thread, but the game code isn't running in the gamePanel.

Controller:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;



public class Controller_LetterFall{
public static void main(String[] args){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            new MainFrame();
        }
    });

  }
}
```

And the MainFrame Class. I try to run gameplay() in a new thread.

```
package wordFall;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements Runnable {

private GamePlay game;
private TextPanel gamePanel;
private Header header;
private Player player;
private Dictionary dictionary;
private GamePlay game;

public MainFrame(){
super("Game");
    // Set the size of the frame.
setSize(400,600);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setVisible(true);


// Establish default player. 
player = new Player();
dictionary = new Dictionary();
game = new GamePlay();
header = new Header();
gamePanel = new TextPanel();
add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

this.game.setBoardInterface( 
        new BoardInterface(){
            @Override
            public void redraw(String text) {
                gamePanel.appendText(text);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        game.play();
        System.out.println("The game is over.");
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any threads in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like a thread safe data container. Lets call it `GameData`. 
Your `GamePlay` object needs to know that `GameData` object and the UI needs to know that as well because changes made by the user has to be propagated to the `GameData` object.

In your `GamePlay` object you can look for changes of the `GameData` object every second or so. If there are changes than you have something to do if not ..

But it would be better use an event like approach i.e. the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). If changes are made by the UI the `GamePlay` will be notified by the observable `GameData` object. 
Furthermore, the UI can be notified as well when data changes.

This seperates the concerns very clearly and follows the Model View Controller pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in this case, your MainFrame object is being constructed from the swing dispatcher thread. As you said, you have to start a new thread somewhere to handle the game. Assuming you would have this code in an instance method of a MainFrame object, that would be:

```
Thread thr = new Thread(this);
thr.start();
```

Then, whenever your separate game thread wants to update the ui object, it should not do it directly, but use SwingUtilities.invokeLater:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        /* Update the ui element... */
}});
```

That runnable will be executed in a swing dispatcher thread when it will have time.

Comment: This will work fine as long as updates aren't too frequent and, more importantly, that the runnable doesn't have any data races or synchronization issues (if it accesses some fields modified in the game thread, this will quickly spell troubles).

Comment: What would be a problem in case of too frequent changes dependent on the game thread's actions?

Comment: Ahh, pressed add by accident. I was also about to say that the thing about data races is correct and synchronization/concurrent collections/whatever are needed if shared data is accessed

Comment: Data races may also be prevented by copying data needed for updates into the runnable (by creating fields or capturing final variables). As for too frequent changes, imagine what would happen if the state is updated 1000 times a second. You'll get lags and very high CPU load. Better send updates in compressed packs in such case or, alternatively, create a GUI timer that will poll the state, say, 25 times per second. It depends on the details which method is better.